# Is there any option to know from which Wifi/network request comment?

Tags: php, laravel, wifi, qr-code

I plan to make a web application. The workflow will be the client scan QR code using his phone to go to some specific URL.

But interested to me is there any option to I can limit visit that URL if the request didn't comment from a specific WiFi network? I do not want to anybody take a photo and fake requests.

Comment: It will be public website or intranet only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it:

1. If your specific WiFi network has a fixed WAN IP / IP range, you can write your application to detect the client IP and check if they came from there. You may check [`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) for the client's IP (if your server is not behind reverse proxy). Your server is still publicly available, but your PHP code will only allow the whitelisted IP to access the certain URL path.
2. If you want even better security, you may place your server in your local network. You can use local IP in your QR code for users to access it. This way, the server will not be available on the internet at all.

Comment: interesting thinking... I like the first one because the server can be in AWS or any other

Comment: If you're talking about EC2, than you can also use their [security group rules](https://aws.amazon.com/tw/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/) to only allow certain source IP(s) to reach your instance's port 80 / 443. You don't even have to program anything. At the same time, you'd lost flexibility to maintain your whitelist with your program (With PHP you could have path based IP whitelist, or use CMS backend to store, control the whitelist, and etc).